# Benchmark A Page Via Windows Command Line and Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, benchmarking

I would like to benchmark the response time of a site as well as simulate a load via the windows command line (WIN+R)

Is this possible?

What is the windows equivalent of this linux command:

```
$ ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://yourpage.com
```

Extra Credit for Powershell 3 Equivalent

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent built-in PowerShell cmdlet that does this. I see from ab's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab) that your command sends 1000 requests, 5 at a time to the web server. You could roll your own solution in PowerShell using either the [`System.Net.WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [`System.Net.HttpwebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) classes, and implement concurrency with PowerShell jobs, parrallel for-loop workflows or asynchronous pipelines, however there are already solutions pre-built for this task like [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).